# Row duplication and row mismatch in mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

my problem is my row in MySQL gets duplicated and mismatch after registration for example 1 person with 3 chickens and it shows in datagridview as 1 person with 3 chickens but if I add another 1 person with 3 chickens both of them gets duplicated by twice(so 12 rows instead of 6rows) and for row mismatch example is **Aentryname has B,C,D chicken** and **Bentryname has E,F,G chicken** and **Bentryname would have B,C,D chicken too** I hope this clarifies everything and sorry for the confusion and it shows in the image I posted here  [DGVdups_and_mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdvTT.png)

this the button add click

````
    Private Sub ButtonAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonAdd.Click
        Dim chicken As New cockeryclass
        Dim dumbbell As New ChickenClass

        Dim fname As String = TextBoxfname.Text
        Dim lname As String = TextBoxlname.Text
        Dim nume As Integer = TextBoxNume3.Text
        Dim ename As String = TextBoxEntryname.Text

        Dim Chicken1 As String = TextBoxChicken1.Text
        Dim Chicken2 As String = TextBoxChicken2.Text
        Dim Chicken3 As String = TextBoxChicken3.Text


        Dim eno1 As String = TextBoxEntryNo1.Text
        Dim eno2 As String = TextBoxEntryNo2.Text
        Dim eno3 As String = TextBoxEntryNo3.Text

        Dim weightlb1 As String = ComboBoxWeightlb1.Text
        Dim weightlb2 As String = ComboBoxWeightlb2.Text
        Dim weightlb3 As String = ComboBoxWeightlb3.Text


        Dim weightoz1 As String = ComboBoxWeightOz1.Text
        Dim weightoz2 As String = ComboBoxWeightOz2.Text
        Dim weightoz3 As String = ComboBoxWeightOz3.Text




        If verif() And chicken.InsertRooster(fname, lname, nume, ename) And dumbbell.insertbreedenolboz1(Chicken1, eno1, weightlb1, weightoz1) And dumbbell.insertbreedenolboz2(Chicken2, eno2, weightlb2, weightoz2) And
            dumbbell.insertbreedenolboz3(Chicken3, eno3, weightlb3, weightoz3) Then

            MsgBox("error")
        Else
            MsgBox("success")

        End If

    End Sub
    Function verif() As Boolean

        If TextBoxfname.Text.Trim = "" Or TextBoxlname.Text.Trim = "" Or TextBoxEntryname.Text.Trim = "" Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If

    End Function


End Class```

this is my 2 classes cockeryclass and Chickenclass


```Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class ChickenClass
    Dim db As New MYCON
    Public Function insertbreedenolboz1(ByVal breed1 As String, ByVal eno1 As String, ByVal weightlb1 As String, ByVal weightoz1 As String) As Boolean

        Using Command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `rooster` (`entry_no`,`chicken`,`lb`,`oz`,`financer_F_id`) VALUES (@eno,@ckn,@lb,@oz)", db.getconnection)
            Command.Parameters.Add("@ckn", MySqlDbType.String).Value = breed1
            Command.Parameters.Add("@eno", MySqlDbType.String).Value = eno1
            Command.Parameters.Add("@lb", MySqlDbType.String).Value = weightlb1
            Command.Parameters.Add("@oz", MySqlDbType.String).Value = weightoz1


            db.openConnection()

            If Command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using

    End Function

    Public Function insertbreedenolboz2(ByVal breed2 As String, ByVal eno2 As String, ByVal weightlb2 As String, ByVal weightoz2 As String) As Boolean
        Using Command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `rooster` (`entry_no`,`chicken`,`lb`,`oz`,`financer_F_id`) VALUES (@eno,@ckn,@lb,@oz)", db.getconnection)
            Command.Parameters.Add("@ckn", MySqlDbType.String).Value = breed2
            Command.Parameters.Add("@eno", MySqlDbType.String).Value = eno2
            Command.Parameters.Add("@lb", MySqlDbType.String).Value = weightlb2
            Command.Parameters.Add("@oz", MySqlDbType.String).Value = weightoz2


            db.openConnection()

            If Command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using

    End Function
    Public Function insertbreedenolboz3(ByVal breed3 As String, ByVal eno3 As String, ByVal weightlb3 As String, ByVal weightoz3 As String) As Boolean
        Using Command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `rooster` (`entry_no`,`chicken`,`lb`,`oz`,`financer_F_id`) VALUES (@eno,@ckn,@lb,@oz)", db.getconnection)
            Command.Parameters.Add("@ckn", MySqlDbType.String).Value = breed3
            Command.Parameters.Add("@eno", MySqlDbType.String).Value = eno3
            Command.Parameters.Add("@lb", MySqlDbType.String).Value = weightlb3
            Command.Parameters.Add("@oz", MySqlDbType.String).Value = weightoz3


            db.openConnection()
If Command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If

        End Using

    End Function

End Class```

```Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class cockeryclass
    Dim db As New MYCON
    Public Function InsertRooster(ByVal fname As String, ByVal lname As String, ByVal nume As String, ByVal ename As String) As Boolean

        Using command As New MySqlCommand("Insert into `derbabe`.`financer`( fname, lname,entry_name,num_entries) values (@fn,@ln,@ename,@nume);", db.getconnection)

            command.Parameters.Add("@fn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fname
            command.Parameters.Add("@ln", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lname
            command.Parameters.Add("@ename", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ename
            command.Parameters.Add("@nume", MySqlDbType.String).Value = nume

            db.openConnection()

            If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using

    End Function

    Public Function inserteno1(ByVal eno1 As String) As Boolean
        Using Command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `rooster` (`entry_no`) VALUES (@eno)", db.getconnection)
            Command.Parameters.Add("@eno", MySqlDbType.String).Value = eno1
            db.openConnection()
            If Command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using

    End Function

    Public Function inserteno2(ByVal eno2 As String) As Boolean
        Using Command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `rooster` (`entry_no`) VALUES (@eno)", db.getconnection)
            Command.Parameters.Add("@eno", MySqlDbType.String).Value = eno2
            db.openConnection()
            If Command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using

    End Function

    Public Function inserteno3(ByVal eno3 As String) As Boolean
        Using Command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `rooster` (`entry_no`) VALUES (@eno)", db.getconnection)
            Command.Parameters.Add("@eno", MySqlDbType.String).Value = eno3
            db.openConnection()
            If Command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using

    End Function

    Function getfighters(ByVal command As MySqlCommand) As DataTable

        command.Connection = db.getconnection
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
        Dim tbl As New DataTable

        adapter.Fill(tbl)

        Return tbl
    End Function

End Class
````

Comment: There's way too much code there. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you can't do that then you haven't spent enough time considering and testing the problem.

Comment: This seems to be a better (although still not ideal) version of a question that was previously deleted. The issue there seemed to be you `SELECT` statement and the fact that you were doing a cross join rather than an inner join, which I mentioned at the time. This new question doesn't even show that query, so my guess is that there's no way to solve your issue here without guessing.

Comment: I think its the If Command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 but im not sure since i just copied the codes from various sources ill try to go in depth with inner join itried it it showed 2 dups the one has the all info but the other its all null

Comment: Basically, make sure that your query is something like `SELECT * FROM Parent INNER JOIN Child ON Parent.PrimaryKey = Child.ForeignKey` and not `SELECT * FROM Parent, Child`. The second is a cross join, which creates a result for every combination of parent row and child row whether they are related or not. You need to specify how the rows are related in order to limit the output to related pairs of rows. You could also use `SELECT * FROM Parent, Child WHERE Parent.PrimaryKey = Child.ForeignKey` but that's considered old syntax now.

Comment: Thank you for the advice it worked and sorry for the confusion i really didn't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Some problems I see with your code...

```
If verif() And chicken.InsertRooster(fname, lname, nume, ename) '...
```

Change your If statement to use `AndAlso` between conditions. This short-circuits the If as it quits as soon as it finds a `False`. This way your database functions won't be executed if `verif` returns `False`.

```
If TextBoxfname.Text.Trim = "" Or TextBoxlname.Text.Trim = "" '...
```

Likewise, `OrElse` will short-circuit the If as soon as a condition returns `True`.

```
Dim nume As Integer = TextBoxNume3.Text
```

The `.Text` property of a `TextBox` is a `String`. With `Option Strict` on (and it should be on) you cannot assign an `String` to a variable of type `Integer`.

```
If verif() AndAlso chicken.InsertRooster(fname, lname, nume, ename) '...
```

and

```
Public Function InsertRooster(ByVal fname As String, ByVal lname As String, ByVal nume As String, '...
```

Your cannot pass and `Integer` (`nume`) to a `Function` that is expecting a `String` (`ByVal nume As String`). I changed the declaration of `nume` to a `String`.

```
      MsgBox("error")
    Else
        MsgBox("success")
```

I think you have your message boxes reversed.

```
insertbreedenolboz1
insertbreedenolboz2
insertbreedenolboz3
```

Each function does exactly the same thing. You are just sending different parameters. Delete the last 2 and change your button code to just call `insertbreedenolboz1`.

```
inserteno1
inserteno2
inserteno3
```

Same as above. Delete the last 2 and just call `inserteno1`.

```
"INSERT INTO `rooster` (`entry_no`,`chicken`,`lb`,`oz`) VALUES (@eno,@ckn,@lb,@oz)"
```

This insert statement will not work because you have 5 fields but only 4 parameters. I really can't fix this without knowing more so I just deleted `financer_F_id`.

I got rid of whatever `db.Connection` is and used a connection that is local to each method so it can be closed and disposed. The connection string is a class level varaiable.

Your classes can be combined to one `DataAccess` class. Create a connection for each method so you can properly close and dispose the connection.

Check the datatypes of all your fields in the database. It would be unusual for numbers to be stored as strings.

```vb
Private Sub ButtonAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonAdd.Click
    Dim da As New DataAccess

    Dim fname As String = TextBoxfname.Text
    Dim lname As String = TextBoxlname.Text
    Dim nume As String = TextBoxNume3.Text
    Dim ename As String = TextBoxEntryname.Text

    Dim Chicken1 As String = TextBoxChicken1.Text
    Dim Chicken2 As String = TextBoxChicken2.Text
    Dim Chicken3 As String = TextBoxChicken3.Text


    Dim eno1 As String = TextBoxEntryNo1.Text
    Dim eno2 As String = TextBoxEntryNo2.Text
    Dim eno3 As String = TextBoxEntryNo3.Text

    Dim weightlb1 As String = ComboBoxWeightlb1.Text
    Dim weightlb2 As String = ComboBoxWeightlb2.Text
    Dim weightlb3 As String = ComboBoxWeightlb3.Text


    Dim weightoz1 As String = ComboBoxWeightOz1.Text
    Dim weightoz2 As String = ComboBoxWeightOz2.Text
    Dim weightoz3 As String = ComboBoxWeightOz3.Text

    If verif() AndAlso da.InsertRooster(fname, lname, nume, ename) AndAlso da.insertbreedenolboz1(Chicken1, eno1, weightlb1, weightoz1) AndAlso da.insertbreedenolboz1(Chicken2, eno2, weightlb2, weightoz2) AndAlso da.insertbreedenolboz1(Chicken3, eno3, weightlb3, weightoz3) Then
        MsgBox("success")
    Else
        MsgBox("error")
    End If

End Sub

Function verif() As Boolean
    If TextBoxfname.Text.Trim = "" OrElse TextBoxlname.Text.Trim = "" OrElse TextBoxEntryname.Text.Trim = "" Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function



Public Class DataAccess

    Private conString As String = "Your connection string"

    Public Function insertbreedenolboz1(ByVal breed1 As String, ByVal eno1 As String, ByVal weightlb1 As String, ByVal weightoz1 As String) As Boolean
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection(conString)
            Using Command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `rooster` (`entry_no`,`chicken`,`lb`,`oz`,`financer_F_id`) VALUES (@eno,@ckn,@lb,@oz)", cn)
                Command.Parameters.Add("@ckn", MySqlDbType.String).Value = breed1
                Command.Parameters.Add("@eno", MySqlDbType.String).Value = eno1
                Command.Parameters.Add("@lb", MySqlDbType.String).Value = weightlb1
                Command.Parameters.Add("@oz", MySqlDbType.String).Value = weightoz1
                cn.Open()
                If Command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Function InsertRooster(ByVal fname As String, ByVal lname As String, ByVal nume As String, ByVal ename As String) As Boolean
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection(conString)
            Using command As New MySqlCommand("Insert into `derbabe`.`financer`( fname, lname,entry_name,num_entries) values (@fn,@ln,@ename,@nume);", cn)
                command.Parameters.Add("@fn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fname
                command.Parameters.Add("@ln", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lname
                command.Parameters.Add("@ename", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ename
                command.Parameters.Add("@nume", MySqlDbType.String).Value = nume
                cn.Open()
                If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Function inserteno1(ByVal eno1 As String) As Boolean
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection(conString)
            Using Command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `rooster` (`entry_no`) VALUES (@eno)", cn)
                Command.Parameters.Add("@eno", MySqlDbType.String).Value = eno1
                cn.Open()
                If Command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

End Class
```